# Console says that a function of mine is not a function in Vue3 + Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

My code is below

```
//useCollection.vue

import { ref } from 'vue';
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config.js'

const useCollection = async(collection) => {
  const error = ref(null);

  const addDoc = async(data) => {
    error.value = null;
    try {
      const response = await projectFirestore.collection(collection).add(data)
      error.value = null;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
      error.value = err.message
    }
  }
  return { addDoc, error }
}

export default useCollection
```

The code above is being imported into this code

```
<script>
//Form.vue

import { projectAuth, projectFirestore, timestamp } from '../firebase/config.js'
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import useCollection from '../composables/useCollection'

export default {
  setup() {
    const message = ref('');
    const { addDoc, error } = useCollection('message');
    const user = projectAuth.currentUser;

    const handlePress = async() => {
      const data = {
        name: user.displayName,
        message: message.value,
        createdBy: timestamp()
      }
      addDoc(data)
    }
    return { message, error, handlePress }
  }

}
</script>
```

[image]

However, when I try to run the code in the browser, it just tells me that addDoc is not a function. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I did import useCollection.vue into my Form.vue. When I click the button, handlePress runs but when it gets to the addDoc it just prints that addDoc is not a function.
Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: you import `useCollection.vue` ... in that module, you export `async(collection)` - therefore `useCollection` returns a PROMISE - try `const { addDoc, error } = await useCollection('message');` (actually that won't work since your setup function isn't async ... you need to understand what an `async` function returns and how to access it

Comment: @JaromandaX hello good sir, thanks for solving my problem. Did not realize that I cannot import a async function or rather when I do import an async function I would require a certain set-up. I will keep this in mind in the future for sure. If possible you can answer below so I can mark this as a solution to help others. Thanks again!

Comment: `Did not realize that I cannot import a async function` yes you can ... I never said you couldn't ... I just said you need to know how to use async/await

Comment: oh haha i added at the back that I would need a certain set up to apply it. Thanks for answering though it has solved my concerns!